# I need code to delete any particular order using delete button from orders page of burger builder React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This snippet contains code for display of each order on the orders page.

import React from 'react';

```
import classes from './Order.css';

const order = ( props ) => {
const ingredients = [];

for (let ingredientName in props.ingredients) {
    ingredients.push(
        {
            name: ingredientName,
            amount: props.ingredients[ingredientName]
        }
    );
}

const ingredientOutput = ingredients.map(ig => {
    return <span
        style={{
            textTransform: 'capitalize',
            display: 'inline-block',
            margin: '0 8px',
            border: '1px solid #ccc',
            padding: '5px'
            }}
        key={ig.name}>{ig.name} ({ig.amount})</span>;
});
```

This snippet shows the burger ingredients and price for each order:

```
return (
    <div className={classes.Order}>
        <p>Ingredients: {ingredientOutput}</p>
        <p>Price: <strong>USD {Number.parseFloat(props.price).toFixed(2)}</strong></p>

        // I want my button below to delete the particular order

        <button>Delete order</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default order;
```

Comment: No, we are not going to write your code for you.Make some effort yourself.

Comment: is this the Academind course, by Maximilian?

Comment: Yes its the same course @Alioshr

Comment: as explained by @JGrenet this is the mindset you should have here. Just keep in mind that you should do it in an immutable way, without mutating the state. think of the ```filter()``` or ```slice()``` methods as a hint for your state management here.

Comment: If you are having a hard time here, it should be a sign that you need to get back to the language basics. Its very important to understand Js and continue to go deeper in the language itself before shooting out into libraries or frameworks. It took me some suffering to realize this

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you have a list of ingredients that represent your order that you inject as props in the `Order` component. If you want to delete that order, you need to delete the associated ingredients.

Based on that, you should have a function that remove that specific list of ingredients on your parent component. Then you inject this function in a prop of you `Order` component like you did for your `ingredient` prop.

Then, you just have to call this function on the onClick event of your button like that:

```
 <button onClick={this.props.removeOrder}>Delete order</button>
```

If your orders are grouped by orders in an orders array, simply inject the function within child props with the order index. Then your function on your parent side that remove order should take the orderIndex as the argument and remove that specific index in your orders array.

Comment: deleteOrder = () => {
        return{
           ingredients: []
        }  
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.Order}>
            <p>Ingredients: {ingredientOutput}</p>
            <p>Price: <strong>USD {Number.parseFloat( props.price ).toFixed( 2 )}</strong></p>
            <button onClick={this.props.deleteOrder}>Delete order</button>
        </div>
    );
};

Comment: 'deleteOrder' is not defined  no-undef . I get this error

Comment: You should put your `deleteOrder` function in your parent component and inject it in your component `Order` since your ingredients list is also injected within props.

Your code "should" work here if you call your deleteOrder directly in your onClick event by calling it with `deleteOrder` direcly and not by the props object since your `deleteOrder` function is not part of your component props. The main problem is here is  you cannot modify props directly, it's completely forbidden by the framework since it can lead to instability and crashes.

Comment: If you do not understand what im saying here, i'm encouraging you like said @Alioshr to go back to the basics and not burn steps too quickly. Programming need patience, practice and step by step learning. Good luck mate :)